# Alert returning more than once

Tags: javascript

I'm learning JS and I'm trying to solve a coding challenge.  I'm suppose to have an alert tell the user the total generator amount and the total watts when I input the parameters.  Problem is the code reader says that I'm alerting more than one.  What am I doing that is making the alert be called multiple times?  Here was my first attempt:

```
function changePowerTotal(totalMW,genID,status,powerMW){

  if(typeof(status) == "on" || typeof(status) == "ON"){
    alert("Generator #"+genID+" is now on, adding "+powerMW+" MW, for a total of "+ (totalMW) +" MW!");
    return false;
  } else {

    if(totalMW == 0){

       alert("Generator #"+genID+" is now off, removing "+powerMW+" MW, for a total of "+ (powerMW) +" MW!");

    } else {

       alert("Generator #"+genID+" is now off, removing "+powerMW+" MW, for a total of "+ (totalMW - powerMW) +" MW!");
    }

    return false;
  }
}
changePowerTotal(0,2,"off",62);
```

I've also tried this:

```
function changePowerTotal(totalMW,genID,status,powerMW){

  var genStatus = "";

  if(status === "on"){

   genStatus = " is now on, adding "
   totalMW = totalMW + powerMW;

  } else {

   genStatus = " is now off, removing "
   totalMW = totalMW - powerMW;

  }

  alert("Generator #"+genID+genStatus+powerMW+" for a total of "+totalMW+" MW!");

}

changePowerTotal(142,2,"off",62);
```

Comment: Your first example only seems to alert once for **[me](http://jsfiddle.net/npp8w7y8/)**

Comment: Is this a Codecademy thing? A lot of the sites that have their own interpreter for specific answers can be really finnicky. Your code looks fine, but the multiple `alert` statements sound like the culprit here. Again, not wrong...but your second approach is objectively better. Do you get the same complaint from your second version? Or is there another arbitrary problem that its warning you about?

Comment: I'm using CodeSchool, and I get the same error alert with the second solution as well:

Incorrect Submission
Your function is alerting more than once.

It sounds as though it's an error with the interpreter.

Comment: maybe it is just showing the wrong error and the error is actually that you are printing the wrong string? we definitely need more details though if this is not the issue

Comment: Here is the text from the challenge:


Build a function declaration named changePowerTotal that takes in:

The total current power generated (a number)
A generator ID (a number)
The new status of a generator (a string that says “on” or “off”)
And the amount of power produced by that generator (a number)
Your function should:

return the new total of generated power
alert the technician in the following formats
For switching on:

Generator #2 is now on, adding 62 MW, for a total of 62 MW!
Or for switching off:

Generator #2 is now off, removing 62 MW, for a total of 0 MW!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no problem in the function, I am guessing you per accidentally called it twice? 
Please check if you did, there is no way this functions can alert twice. You must have made a mistake in calling it twice.

Comment: I just called it once.  I think maybe I have to code the solution a specific way in order not to get any errors.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for the help.  I found the solution, here it is:

```
function changePowerTotal (totalMW, genID, genStatus,genMW){

  var curStatus = " ";
  var sumMW = 0;

  if(genStatus === "off"){

   curStatus = " is now "+genStatus+", removing ";
   alert("Generator #"+genID+curStatus+genMW+" MW, for a total of "+totalMW+"MW!");
   return totalMW + genMW

  } else {

    curStatus = " is now "+genStatus+", adding ";
    sumMW = genMW + totalMW;
    alert("Generator #"+genID+curStatus+genMW+" MW, for a total of "+(totalMW + genMW)+"MW!");
    return totalMW + genMW

  }  
}
```

Comment: how does this work when you are supposed to subtract for powering off? you dont do it for your return value nor your alerted string

Comment: I tried a solution with the function subtracting and it wouldn't pass.  I'm assuming they just wanted one "on" and one "off" with 0 totalMW.  I tried so many variations and this is the only one that would pass.